# Quicksort not sorting

Tags: java, quicksort

So I am trying to create a quicksort method, however, it is not sorting properly. Heres my input and output
Original array:
80.0 10.0 50.0 70.0 60.0 90.0 20.0 30.0 40.0 0.0
Sorted array:
0.0 30.0 20.0 80.0 40.0 60.0 70.0 10.0 90.0 50.0

I tried changing the for loop to `for(int i = left; i < right; i++)`
but now the output is:
0.0 20.0 30.0 40.0 80.0 10.0 60.0 90.0 70.0 50.0

```
    public static void sort(double[] a)
    {
        quickSort(a, 0, a.length-1);
    }

    public static void quickSort(double [] a, int left, int right)
    {
        if (left < right)
        {
            int pivotIndex = (left+right)/2;
            int pos = partition(a,left,right,pivotIndex);
            quickSort(a,left,pos-1);
            quickSort(a,pos+1,right);
        }
    }

    private static int partition(double [] a, int left,int right,int pivotIndex)
    {
        double temp = a[pivotIndex];
        a[pivotIndex] = a[right];
        a[right] = temp;
        int pos = left;//represents boundary between small and large elements
        for(int i = left; i < right-1; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] <= a[pivotIndex])
            {
                double temp2 = a[i];
                a[i] = a[pos];
                a[pos] = temp2;
                pos++;
            }
        }
        double temp3 = a[pivotIndex];
        a[pivotIndex] = a[pos];
        a[pos] = temp3;
        return pos;
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what you want to do:

```
private static void swap(double[] a, int i, int j) {
    double t = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = t;
}

private static int partition(double [] a, int left,int right,int pivotIndex)
{
    swap(a, pivotIndex, right);
    int pos = left;//represents boundary between small and large elements
    for(int i = left; i < right; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] < a[right])
        {
            swap(a, i, pos);
            pos++;
        }
    }
    swap(a, right, pos);
    return pos;
}
```

I made the code clearer by having a helper `swap` method. You had 3 bugs in the original code:

- The one-off error on the loop boundary
- You're using the wrong index to get the pivot element in the loop
- You swapped elements at the wrong indices after the loop

Comment: Passing pivotIndex as parameter is useless, it would be more efficient to compute it inside partition (and avoid all the swaping stuff by the way)... the pivot position is allready returned by partition anyway.

Comment: I didn't want to change his original code too much; I just wanted to correct any mistakes I see. Refactoring the swap was done for clarity, not efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
for(int i = left; i < right-1; i++)
```

to

```
for(int i = left; i < right; i++)
```

Comment: that didnt work, my output now is: 0.0 20.0 30.0 40.0 80.0 10.0 60.0 90.0 70.0 50.0

Comment: the last swap must be between pos and right, not between pos and pivotIndex

Comment: and inside the loop, the pivot value is at `a[right]`, not `a[pivotIndex]`.